# Half-Life Determination

Tags: c++, function, file, visual-c++, menu

Here is the problem I am working on:

> You are to develop a menu-driven program that will allow the analyses of data from the file `Patient_Data.txt` using the following equations:
>   [Half-Life Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TapFv.png)
>
> > Ct = C0e^-kt
> >
> > t½  = ln(2)/k
>
> where:
>   **Ct** is the concentration in ug/L at time t
>   **C0** is the initial concentration in ug/L
>   **t** is the time in hrs
>   **k** is the time constant (1/hrs)
>   **t½** is the half-life in hrs
>
> - The user of the program must be able to obtain the average half-life (to 2 decimal places) along with the number of measurements used to calculate the average for any of the 5 patients for which data has been collected.
> - The program must also be able to display the 2 patient numbers and averages of the patients that have the highest half-life average values.
> - A menu must be used to select the different options with an additional option for Exit. The program must run until exit is selected by the user.
> - The program must be designed using functions.
>
>   - A function called `analyzeData` must take as input the patient number and must return both the average half-life and the number of measurements in the average for the input patient number.
>   - A separate function called `halfLife` is to be used for calculating the t½ (half-life) based on C0 (initial concentration), Ct (concentration at time t) and t (time) that are in the data file.
>   - A third function called `highest2halfLifes` must also be used to determine the two patients with the longest average half-life from the five different patients. All four values (`patient1`, `halfLife1`, `patient2`, `halfLife2`) must be returned to the main function.

The following data file `Patient_Data.txt` lists values for C0, Ct, and t, respectively [(Patient Data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gcd7.png)

```
1 325 160 2.0
1 600 100 6.2
2 325 220 1.0
3 600 200 4.4
4 325 100 3.0
4 325 88 3.2
2 600 200 3.3
2 325 100 3.3
4 600 210 3.4
5 325 105 3.5
1 600 110 6.0
3 325 100 3.1
2 600 120 5.5
2 600 125 5.5
5 120 60 2.2
2 325 100 3.4
```

---

Comment: You can't return two values from a function, you've just become a victim of "comma operator confusion". `return var1, var2;` does not return `var1` and `var2`. It invokes the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: `analyzeData` returns *one* value, a `double`. To return two values, use `std::pair`, reference parameters, or pointer parameters.

Comment: We have only learned how to use pointers so that would be the preferred  method. How would I do this for values I want returned from a function, rather than called into a function? @molbdnilo